# JQuery trouble understanding event order

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Bootstrap dropdown menu with two sub-menus. My problem is that the dropdowns are dynamically created after the document is loaded, and don't respond to how I would normally get them to work.
How I would normally go about it would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    addItem(); //adds the first instance of the drop down
    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("open");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

But this obviously doesn't work for dynamically created content. I saw elsewhere online that this would work for dynamic content;

```
//still has first instance of dropdown, just later in the doc
$(document).on('click', 'ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("open");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
});
```

but for the life of me, I can't figure out why this doesn't work. What I'm seeing is that it is adding the open class to the sub-menu, but toggle the parent menu(not stopping propagation?) So, my question is, why doesn't the second one execute as expected, and how can I make it?

List structure for reference:

```
<div class="dropdown open">
  <button id="select0" class="btn new-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Select Your Item <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="sub" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a data-def-cost="6">Item 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a data-def-cost="8">Item 1.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="sub" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a data-def-cost="5">Item 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a data-def-cost="3">Item 2.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a data-plu="xyz" data-def-cost="8.00">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-plu="xyz" data-def-cost="8.00">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a data-plu="xyz" data-def-cost="10.00">Item 5</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Other Items</li>
    <li><a data-plu="143">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a data-plu="xyz">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a data-plu="xyz">Item 8</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="input1">
  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="otherinput1">
</div>
```

Comment: it's because, while Bootstrap will do it for you, it doesn't know what order you want them in. So that has to be done somewhat manually. At least, in my experience.

Comment: Indeed I tried by myself and i stumbled upon the same problem.

Comment: Fixed to deal with more than 2 levels of submenus : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597575/1636522.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).siblings()` points to an `ul` element, however, the `.open` class is supposed to be added to the parent `li` : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage.

> Via data attributes or JavaScript, the dropdown plugin toggles hidden content (dropdown menus) by toggling the `.open` class on the parent list item.

Here is a suggestion (inspired by the following code snippet : [Multi-Level Dropdowns](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h)) :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // this variable keeps track of the last open menus
  // in order to close them when another link is clicked
  // or when the entire dropdown is closed
  var open;
  $("#my-dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function () {
    if (open) open.removeClass("open");
  });
  $(".dropdown-submenu > a").on("click", function (e) {
    if (open) open.removeClass("open");
    open = $(this).parents(".dropdown-submenu");
    open.addClass("open");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown" id="my-dropdown">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action 1.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action 2.2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#">Submenu 2.3</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action 2.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action 2.3.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure as to efficiency of my solution, but I rearranged the order a bit, and forced the parent to stay open

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]', function(e){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("open");
    $(this).parent().addClass("open");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("open");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and this solved my issue

Comment: I don't recommend attaching that event handler to `document`, since it will be triggered on every click anywhere in the document. Instead, attach it to the lowest-level element that will persist amongst object creations. In your case, that's probably something like `div.dropdown`

Comment: @Palpatim, I tried that, and it doesn't seem to help. Using an alert, I can see that it isn't even finding the click even unless I have it higher in the tree. The lowest it seems to start finding it is
    $('body')

Answer (score 0):

use one of these below lines.

```
$(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
$(this).next('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
```